# How to display the value of a Search Result Collection from Active Directory in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, active-directory

My boss sends me a txt file with some id numbers. I need to get some info from users that have those id numbers.

I've never done anything with Active Directory so I'm a little lost. Right now, I'm just trying to make sure that I can access the "muID" property from AD. But when I search AD for the property and try to get the value of the property I get an output of it "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection" instead of the value, which should be similar to "111123456."

Here is my code so far:

```
SearchResultCollection sResults = null;
string path = "LDAP://muad1";

DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);

dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
dSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("muID");

SearchResultCollection results = dSearcher.FindAll();

if (results != null)
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {                    
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

But that's not working. I've tried searching around but I can't anything that works. I've tried this

```
Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["muID"].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(dEntry.Properties[result].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(dEntry.Properties[result][0].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(dEntry.Properties["result"].ToString());
```

but none of them work. They either throw an error or do the same thing that the one on the code block does.

Again, I want to make sure that I'm accessing that property so I can then get the info that I want. I thought displaying the value of the property would be a good way to check. But it is not displaying the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I feel like you're so close.

A `SearchResultCollection` contains `SearchResult` instances: [Info on SearchResultCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

A `SearchResult` contains a `Properties` property: [Info on SearchResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

`SearchResult` `Properties` is a `ResultPropertyCollection`: [Info on ResultPropertyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.resultpropertycollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you update your code from

```
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

to:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["muID"][0].ToString());
```

then you should find what you're looking for. To be safe I would also make sure before accessing the element at [0], you check to make sure it exists first. You might run into an exception if a user doesn't have that property at all.

Edit:
This might help you to see what property and value pairs are available for you to use. If you don't see "muID" anywhere then that's why you're getting an error.

```
if (results != null)
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {                    
        foreach(string propName in result.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            foreach(object myCollection in result.Properties[propName])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propName + " : " + myCollection.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I got an out of bounds exception :(

Comment: It sounds like it's not part of the collection then. It means there's an entity that doesn't have a value for ["muID"]. I'll see if I can write something to help.

Comment: Updated @Nivek Maybe this will help you narrow down the problem

Comment: The key here is that if the attribute is empty in AD, then it doesn't get returned at all - it won't exist in your `result` collection at all - even if you asked for it. The method KSib gives to check will work. You can also use `if (result.Properties.Contains("muID"))` to see if the attribute was returned.